# Deploying create React App to shared hosting

Tags: reactjs

This is the first time I want to deploy my react app and I am unable to find any concrete article which tells how one can deploy app to a shared hosting.

I have already executed the command `npm run build` which generated a build folder.

Previously, I thought if I click on Index.html file inside that build folder, It will open the site I created but all it did was to open a blank page.

So, how can I push my site to a shared hosting like hostgator/Godaddy/Namecheap (since they all use CPanel)?

**Update:** In case it helps someone, I figured out the solution and updated it with screenshot for another user facing the same problem: Link to answer ->
[How to host a ReactJS project on a static server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618411/how-to-host-a-reactjs-project-on-a-static-server/52618467#52618467)

Comment: By default, CRA assumes that you host your code in the root directory of your server.If you're happy with that you can use an FTP (like filezilla) to upload contents in build folder and upload it to your server (or via cpanel) root (ie, index.html should be accessible via `yourdomainname.domain`)

Comment: Did the create-react-app user guide not help? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment if not, what didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening your project from your filesystem is a different thing from opening it from http[s] protocol. Long story short — your javascript code probably didn't load correctly and never got rendered in the first place.

In order for your app to work, it needs to be opened with http, or in other words being served on http server (apache/nginx), and that what your hosting does for you. CPanel is just an interface to tune it for your needs.

In order to upload your project, first you have to create FTP user (or use one that already exists. I prefer creating one user/project).

Next, download any FTP client (FileZilla is kinda standard) and connect to your domain/IP using created user.

Find folder, where your site is being hosted from and upload all the files there.

I'm pretty sure each hosting has instructions in their FAQ section so be sure to read that through as well.

Happy coding!

Comment: This post is totally theoratical doesn't help it at all! in real world it's different.