# How to host a ReactJS project on a static server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a built a React application and it runs fine from the local server. However, when I run npm run build, the process appears to execute correctly (creates build folder, which contains the bundled js file and the index.html file), but when I open index.html in my browser it renders nothing. I read something about static server to use node.js, the problem is, Im paying hostgator and to use a static server I need to pay for month almost the amount that Im paying for year, there is some way to run it on a server without node, apache etc? (because the project is already done)... Thanks guys appreciate!

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

On the place you are putting your build file (screenshot at last)

You need to create `.htacces` file

Copy  and paste this content in that `.htacces`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It should probably work now.

**[Note:]** Try creating it using `file` option in your Cpanel and once it is created, edit .htacess file and paste the above code snippet  (3rd and 4th Image).

Something like this

[image]

**Where .htacess file looks like this** 
[image]

**adding new file**
[image]

**Click on .htacess file and then select edit to edit it**
[image]

Comment: Thanksss a million!!

Comment: @JaderCosta Mark it as answered if this worked for you :)